# Getting Session variable directly on jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I would like to know is there a way to get the session variable directly in jQuery or not?
My Requirement is to pass a secret token in every request which is already available in session. As it's a secret token I can't add it as a hidden parameter in jsp, where it will be exposed by viewing source.

Hence OnSubmit of the form, I call the jQuery function and attempting to add an additional parameter which is already available in session. But I couldn't find a way to get the session variable inside jQuery function.

Any help in this regard would be most welcome. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: A session variable isn't something that just exists, it's something most serverside languages have a method of creating for you so you can store data persitently across a session. This is usually done on the serverside, especially if security is an issue, as anything stored clientside is easily available to the user, and the session data being serverside means that the only way to get at it with javascript is with ajax or just sending it to the client with the markup.

Comment: If the parameter is already in session, why to recover it in client side? It can be obtained in server side with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/#dom-localstorage) and its methods `.setItem()` and `getItem()`.

Example :

```
localStorage.setItem('token', 'your_token');
...
localStorage.getItem('token');
```